# how to use pre-installed binaries (zeromq) in npm install instead of build by node-gyp tool?

Tags: node.js, zeromq, node-gyp

i am on alpine:3.6 i've already installed zeromq binary from (compiled from source) on system.

and now i want to use nodejs's binding for this.
so using https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node

here is some instruction here in which we can build library from source.
https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node/wiki/Installation#installation-on-linux--bsd-without-root-access

we can complie lib on our own but that places binaries in same folder, but instead i want npm to use library which installed in system (/use/local)
as far as i can gess its game of these two lines which i don't much knowledge about it

```
export CXXFLAGS="-I $(readlink -f ../include)"
export LDFLAGS="-L $(readlink -f ../lib) -Wl,-rpath=$(readlink -f ../lib)"
```

then `npm install` will use libs what we just complied in `zeromq` folder

i don't have much knowledge of CXXFLAGS and LDFLAGS so is that possible.

Answer (score 0):

The installation instructions you cite are for peopel without `root` access, which are therefore unable to install software in the "usual places" like `/usr` or `/usr/local`. If you install a library into an "unusual place" like your home directory, you have to tell the compiler and linker where the library can be found. Thats the use of `CXXFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` in this case. Since you seem to have `root` access and installed the ZeroMQ library in an "usual place", `npm install zmq` should work without you having the set these varaibales.

**Update:** The above seems to be not working. However, according to https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node#project-status, this module is deprecated anyway. The new `zeromq` model works without compilation for me. See this minimal Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine

RUN npm install zeromq
```

**Note:** This does not use the pre-installed library but a pre-build one instead. However, you could leave out the pre-installed library from the base image to save size.

Comment: its not working, and its trying to compile from source.. which i don't want because in my case i just want ship lightweight app, where our docker container image already have libzmq pre installed..

Comment: so i want npm install to use preinstallled zmq instead of compiling it again, that compilation takes time which is problem for me.. is there any way you know to get npm install to use systme lib insead of building new from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

it is possible now, with 6-beta.4, just tested

> npm install zeromq@6.0.0-beta.4 --zmq-shared

in a system with zeromq package is installed, i.e. in alpine

> apk add zeromq-dev

I am almost sure that -dev package is not required, but I did not tested

**UPDATE (few minute later)**

It is possible to use zmq as external library, it requires anyway a compilation, but without downloading all package.
Give that the zeromq-dev is installed

> apk add zeromq-dev

(in this case -dev is required), then

> npm i zeromq-stable --zmq-external

will compile the nodejs module, but not the zeromq library itself, a very faster option, but still not getting the lightweight docker image you need